# Database cleaning with R

Tags: r, database

I have a dataset like this:

```
a1 <- c("10/10/2023  00:00:08","10/10/2023  00:00:08","10/10/2023  00:00:08", "10/10/2023  00:00:08", "10/10/2023  00:00:16", "10/10/2023  00:00:16", "10/10/2023  00:00:16", "10/10/2023  00:00:16")
b1 <- c(7, 7, 7,5, 4, 4, 3, 3)
c1 <- c("A","B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D")
m1 <- data.frame(a1, b1, c1)
```

and I want something like that:

```
time <- c("10/10/2023  00:00:08","10/10/2023  00:00:16")
A <- c(7, 4)
B <- c(7, 4)
C <- c(7, 3)
D <- c(5, 3)
m <- data.frame(time, A, B, C, D)
```

how cai I do it?

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(m1, names_from = c1, values_from = b1)`